# get result of request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this:

`file accounts.controlles.ts`

```
import { requestT } from "src/service/request.api";

export const getaccounts = async () => {
    const response = await requestT({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/accounts",
    }); 
    return response;
};
```

`file header.tsx`

```
import { getaccounts } from "src/controllers/accounts.controller";

export default function Header() {

    const listaccounts =  async () => { return await getaccounts(); };
    console.log("listaccounts: ", listaccounts);

}
```

but I got this on console:

```
listaccounts:  async ()=>{
        return (0,src_controllers_accounts_controller__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.getaccounts)();
    }
```

I just want get the items of service `getaccounts`  , why I'm getting the arrow function???.....

I test the function `getaccounts`, I added `console.log(response)` and I got the items, what can I do to get it on `header.tsx`??

Comment: `listaccounts` as you've defined it is simply a function that calls another async function. You are printing the function definition. You've never called the actual function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listaccounts` as you've defined it is simply an async function that calls another async function. **You are printing the function definition. You never called the actual function.**

Try calling the function, awaiting its return, then logging the result. Note that to call an async function this way, the caller must also be async.

```js
export default async function Header() {

    const listaccounts =  async () => { return await getaccounts(); };
    const accounts = await listaccounts();
    console.log("listaccounts: ", accounts);

}
```

If you don't want to make `Header` async, then you can simply provide the callback behavior to print the accounts after they are available. The `.then()` method works well for this.

```js
export default function Header() {

    const listaccounts =  async () => { return await getaccounts(); };
    listaccounts().then(accounts => {
        console.log("accounts: ", accounts);
    });
}
```

Comment: on this line ```await listaccounts();``` I get one issue, on ```await```   I get this ```await isn't allowed in non-async function```

Comment: That error is related to calling an async function from another function that isn't async. Making the `Header` function async will resolve the error, but note that the caller of `Header()` must consequentially be async.

Comment: @jhonestrada I updated the answer to provide more options

Comment: thanls bro, it work

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what you said to JS to print.

You need to invoke the function in the console.log, if you're expecting for something else.